How can I make elements appear at the bottom of a ScrollView?
I have a SwiftUI related question. I'm trying to make a chat and make messages appear at the bottom of the screen (like at the screen from Telegram). All solutions I tried keep rendering messages at the top. Documentation and ChatGPT couldn't solve my problem.
The thing I tried the first was to use defaultScrollAnchor(_ anchor:) modifier to ScrollView. That didn't work and moreover I didn't notice any changes using this modifier. Neither .top, .center, or .top parameters didn't change anything. I tried both on static and dynamic list of elements in ScrollView. My code inside the ScrollView looks like that:
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
            Text(chat.message)
                .id(chat.id)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}

Then I tried to scroll to the bottom using onAppear{} and onChange{} modifiers with help of ScrollViewReader and scrollTo(_ id:anchor:). That didn't work either. As a last resort I'm asking this question here. Spacer() didn't work either. Here is my complete code for the last implementation:
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
                Text(chat.message)
                    .id(chat.id)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .onAppear {
        scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
    }
    .onChange(of: viewModel.location.chat) {
        scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
    }
}

And scrollToBottom function:
private func scrollToBottom(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let lastMessage = viewModel.location.chat.last {
            proxy.scrollTo(lastMessage.id, anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
}


Here I isolated the logic of the code keeping the structure:
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
                            Text(chat.message)
                                .id(chat.id)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
                }
                .onChange(of: viewModel.location.chat) {
                    scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
                }
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Message", text: $viewModel.currentMessage)
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
                    .overlay {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                    }
                Button {
                    viewModel.sendMessage()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.accentColor)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom], 12)
        }
    }
    
    private func scrollToBottom(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let lastMessage = viewModel.location.chat.last {
                proxy.scrollTo(lastMessage.id, anchor: .bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel(location: Location(name: "Test locaiton")))
}

struct Location: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var chat: [StringChatMessage]
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.chat = []
    }
}

struct StringChatMessage: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var isUser: Bool
    var message: String
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var location: Location
    @Published var currentMessage: String = ""
    
    init(location: Location) {
        self.location = location
    }
    
    func sendMessage() {
        guard !currentMessage.isEmpty else { return }
        location.chat.append(StringChatMessage(isUser: true, message: currentMessage))
        location.chat.append(StringChatMessage(isUser: false, message: "*reply*"))
        currentMessage = ""
    }
}



Your code looks good, assuming your Chat items implement Identifable. I tried it with a dummy implementation of Chat and it works for me, the ScrollView scrolls to the last chat item on first show. Try checking how the id of your chat items is defined - make sure the ids don't change (for example, if the array held by your viewModel is copied). You could also try using .scrollPosition in connection with .scrollTargetLayout, instead of using a ScrollViewReader. For more help, please supplement your example code so that it is complete and runs in isolation.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@BenzyNeez I updated the post and added isolated example keeping the structure.

@BenzyNeez Also I tried running this implementation on both simulator and device. It doesn't work in either case

Thanks for updating the post to include more code.
When I try the code on an iPhone 15 simulator running iOS 17.5 (Xcode 15.4) it works fine for me.

If I start with an empty list and send lots of messages, the view starts to scroll when it reaches the bottom of the screen and the latest message is always visible.
If I pre-load ViewModel with a bunch of messages, it scrolls to the last message on launch.

To pre-load the messages, I updated ViewModel.init:
init(location: Location) {
    self.location = location
    for i in 1...100 {
        currentMessage = "Message \(i)"
        sendMessage()
    }
}

So I don't really know, why it is not working for you. Still, there are a few things I would suggest that you change. I don't really think the changes will help resolve the issue (which I can't reproduce), but they might help to improve the code a little:

If you want to pass in the viewModel to ContentView, then use @ObservedObject instead of @StateObject. Alternatively, keep it as a @StateObject and create the model in ContentView. In the latter case, it should also be private:

// ContentView
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel(
    location: Location(name: "Test location")
)


In Location and StringChatMessage, use let for the id:

let id = UUID()


Since StringChatMessage implements Identifiable, there is no need to set an .id on the items in the ForEach:

ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
    Text(chat.message)
        // .id(chat.id)
}


In the function scrollToBottom, there is no need to call .scrollTo asynchronously. However, you might like to call it withAnimation, so that the scrolling is animated:

private func scrollToBottom(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
    if let lastMessage = viewModel.location.chat.last {
        withAnimation {
            proxy.scrollTo(lastMessage.id, anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
}


Currently, the draft message is saved in ViewModel as currentMessage and then sent when sendMessage is called. But will there really be any other observers of the current message, apart from ContentView? I would suggest making currentMessage a @State variable in ContentView and passing the text of the message as parameter to sendMessage:

// ViewModel
// @Published var currentMessage: String = ""

func sendMessage(text: String) {
    location.chat.append(StringChatMessage(isUser: true, message: text))
    location.chat.append(StringChatMessage(isUser: false, message: "*reply*"))
}

// ContentView
@State private var currentMessage: String = ""

TextField("Message", text: $currentMessage)
    // ... modifiers as before
Button {
    viewModel.sendMessage(text: currentMessage)
    currentMessage = ""
} label: {
    // ...
}


As I was suggesting in a comment, you could use .scrollPosition in connection with .scrollTargetLayout and remove the ScrollViewReader altogether. This might be simpler, not least, because you don't need to pass the ScrollViewProxy as parameter to scrollToBottom:

// ContentView
@State private var scrollPosition: UUID?

// ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyVStack {
            // ...
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .bottom)
    .onAppear {
        scrollToBottom()
    }
    .onChange(of: viewModel.location.chat) {
        scrollToBottom()
    }
// }

private func scrollToBottom() {
    if let lastMessage = viewModel.location.chat.last {
        withAnimation {
            scrollPosition = lastMessage.id
        }
    }
}


If you supply initial: true to the .onChange modifier then you could drop the .onAppear callback. You could also get the last message from the updated array that is passed to the closure, which means you could do all the automated scrolling in the .onChange callback and drop the function scrollToBottom too.

Here is the fully-updated ContentView, which works this way:
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel(
        location: Location(name: "Test location")
    )
    @State private var currentMessage: String = ""
    @State private var scrollPosition: UUID?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
                        Text(chat.message)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .bottom)
            .onChange(of: viewModel.location.chat, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                if let lastMessage = newVal.last {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollPosition = lastMessage.id
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Message", text: $currentMessage)
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
                    .overlay {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.4))
                    }
                Button {
                    viewModel.sendMessage(text: currentMessage)
                    currentMessage = ""
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane.fill")
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.accentColor)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing, .bottom], 12)
        }
    }
}


EDIT In your comment, you explained that you want the content inside the ScrollView to start at the bottom instead of at the top. To get it working this way:

wrap the ScrollView with a GeometryReader, to measure the space being used
set the height of the ScrollView as the minHeight on the LazyVStack, with alignment of .bottom.

GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        LazyVStack {
            // ...
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: proxy.size.height, alignment: .bottom)
    }
    // ...other modifiers as before
}


EDIT2 Regarding animation - if I understand correctly, you want a new message to be added to the bottom of an empty ScrollView with some kind of push animation from the bottom, right? You could try these changes:

Add a .transition modifier to the Text showing a message:

Text(chat.message)
    .transition(.push(from: .bottom))


Wrap the call to sendMessage with withAnimation:

Button {
    withAnimation {
        viewModel.sendMessage(text: currentMessage)
    }
    currentMessage = ""
} label: {
    // ...
}


Thanks for the useful suggestions on how to improve my code. I will definitely use them.
As I can see my question wasn't clear enough. My ScrollView behave just like you described it in your bullet list at the start of the answer. But that is not the behaviour I need to achieve. I need messages to appear at the bottom near the text filed from the start. I provided screenshot of a desired behaviour at the top of my question. Please see the example here

@Sasha OK, update added to end of answer

Many thanks! This solution finally works. I have another small question regarding this solution. Animation is applied only when messages cover the whole ScrollView. I tried applying animation in action of a button but they differ in style. I understand why it happens but it's not clear for me how I can make them happen in one style. Leaving animation only in the button stops animating when there are lots of messages.

@Sasha Pleased to have been able to help, thanks for accepting the answer! Regarding the animation - answer updated again with some suggested changes. If this is not quite working as you want then I would suggest creating a new post to explore other solutions - be sure to provide the working code as starting point!

To make chat messages appear at the bottom of the screen in a SwiftUI chat application, you can use ScrollViewReader to control the scroll position programmatically. Here is a working solution:
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChatViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(viewModel.location.chat) { chat in
                        Text(chat.message)
                            .id(chat.id)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .onAppear {
                scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.location.chat) { _ in
                scrollToBottom(proxy: proxy)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func scrollToBottom(proxy: ScrollViewProxy) {
        if let lastMessage = viewModel.location.chat.last {
            withAnimation {
                proxy.scrollTo(lastMessage.id, anchor: .bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ChatViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var location: ChatLocation
    
    init(location: ChatLocation) {
        self.location = location
    }
}

struct ChatLocation {
    var chat: [ChatMessage]
}

struct ChatMessage: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let message: String
}

// Example usage with mock data
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ChatViewModel(location: ChatLocation(chat: [
        ChatMessage(id: UUID(), message: "Hello!"),
        ChatMessage(id: UUID(), message: "How are you?"),
        // Add more messages as needed
    ]))
    
    var body: some View {
        ChatView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

Ensure your viewModel.location.chat is correctly identified as @Published so SwiftUI can react to changes.
Use ScrollViewReader with onAppear and onChange to automatically scroll to the bottom whenever messages are added or the view appears.

It seems like that's exactly what I'm doing right now but the messages keep appearing at the top. I checked and location inside my viewModel is marked as @Published. The thing is that this solution doesn't work and I don't have a clue what might be the problem here.
